# Is there a way to convert RedisValue[] to string[]?

Tags: json, stackexchange.redis

I have an array `RedisValue[]` returned from the `StackExchange.Redis` client.  I want to take each of the values (which are actually `JSON` strings) in the array and join them together to get a valid `JSON` string that I can return to the client.

Here's what I want to do...

```
var results = redis.HashGet("srch", ArrayOfRedisKeys[]);

string returnString = "[" + string.Join(results, ",") + "]";
```

However, this doesn't work because `results` is an array of `RedisValue` not an array of `string`.  Is there a straight-forward and performant way to do this other than just iterating the `RedisValue` array?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not currently, but I have [just pushed](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/commit/dd9e9c8df8111bcac06ffdc3f6afd301ae424216) the following extension method into `ExtensionMethods.cs`:

```
    static readonly string[] nix = new string[0];
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an array of strings from an array of values
    /// </summary>
    public static string[] ToStringArray(this RedisValue[] values)
    {
        if (values == null) return null;
        if (values.Length == 0) return nix;
        return Array.ConvertAll(values, x => (string)x);
    }
```

So: in the next build, you can just use `results.ToStringArray()`. Until then, you could just copy the above locally.

Comment: ALERT. Note if values is null, you never going to succeed with `values.ToStringArray()`, so better to use it like `ToStringArray(values)` without extension method `this`

Comment: @Jaider you can call extension methods on `null` values. The following will work just fine: `RedisValue[] vals = null; string[] foo = vals.ToStringArray();` - `foo` will be `null`, because of the first `return`. This works *precisely because* the compiler simply rewrites this as `string[] foo = ExtensionMethods.ToStringArray(vals);`

Comment: Wow, I am impressed! then disregard my previous comment :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Hmm.. When I use the method on fx MEMORY STATS, where I change the RedisValue[] to RedisResult[] I get an error stating, that InvalidCastException, since in index 16, I have a array inside the array - any solution / suggestion for that?

Comment: @badaboomskey can you be more specific? You should have a RedisResult - since it is an atypical result structure, you'll have to explore it manually checking each node. Is there a specific problem you're seeing that we can discuss with an example?